On index of congruence subgroups
Let $k$ be the non-archimedean local field, $\mathfrak{o}$ its ring of integer, $\mathfrak{p}$ the unique maximal ideal of $\mathfrak{o}$, and $\varpi$ a uniformizer.
Let $K_0(n)=\{\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix};c\in\varpi^n\mathfrak{o}\}\subset\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathfrak{o})$.
I  have no idea on computing the subgroup index $[\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathfrak{o}):K_0(n)]$? Is ther any good way to see this? Thank you!
Edit:
Let $K_1(n)=\{\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix};c\in\varpi^n\mathfrak{o},d\in1+\varpi^n\mathfrak{o}\}$
First consider $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathfrak{o})\rightarrow\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{p}^n)$ with kernel $K(n)=\{\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\equiv\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\mod\varpi^n\}$, we have $[\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathrm{o}):K(n)]=|\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{p}^n)|$
Sencond, we consider $K_1(n)\rightarrow\mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{p}^n$ by $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\mapsto\overline{b}$ is that the kernel be $K(n)$?
consider $K_0(n)\rightarrow(\mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{p}^n)^*$ by $\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&d\end{bmatrix}\mapsto\overline{b}$, with kernel is $K_1(n)$, we have $[K_0(n):K_1(n)]=|(\mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{p}^n)^*|$
To calculate the index $[\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathfrak{o}):K_0(n)]$, I still have the problem on the second part$(?)$.
If this is wrong. I have another idea: Following the same method on $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathfrak{o})$.
Consider $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathfrak{o})\rightarrow\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{p}^n)$, but then I need to compute the index $[\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathfrak{o}):\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathfrak{o})]$. But $\mathrm{det}:\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathfrak{o})\rightarrow\mathfrak{o}^*$, with kernel $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathfrak{o})$, so $[\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathfrak{o}):\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathfrak{o})]=|\mathfrak{o}^*|$ is not even finite?
So, I don't know how actually to compute the index $[\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathfrak{o}):K_0(n)]$.

First, show that the reduction map $\text{GL}_2(\mathcal O)\to \text{GL}_2(\mathcal O/\varpi^n)$ is surjective. Let $K(n)$ be the kernel. Let $K_1(n)=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}\in K(n)\colon c\equiv 0\mod \varpi^n\right\}$. Show that the map $K_1(n)\to \mathcal O/\varpi^n$ that takes a matrix to the upper right entry is surjective. Notice that its kernel is $K(n)$. Now prove that the map $K_0(n)\to (\mathcal O/\varpi^n)^*$ that takes a matrix to its lower right entry is surjective. Now notice that $[\text{GL}_2(\mathcal O):K(n)]=[\text{GL}_2(\mathcal O):K_0(n)][K(n):K_0(n)]=[\text{GL}_2(\mathcal O):K_0(n)][K(n):K_1(n)][K_1(n):K_0(n)]$.
Finally, compute $|\text{GL}_2(\mathcal O/\varpi^n)|,|\mathcal O/\varpi^n|,|(\mathcal O/\varpi^n)^*|$ and put everything together.

Ok! thanks for your answer! I have question on how to compute the order of $(\mathfrak{o}/\varpi^n)^*$ ?

I'm not sure if $(\mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{p}^n)^*$ is still a field or not, if not, how to compute its order directly?

This question makes no sense, since you don't have addition. It is a group with respect to multiplication.

OK! so, how can I compute the order of $(\mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{p}^n)^*$?

I think that the definition of $K_1$ is wrong? it must be the $c\equiv 0\ \ \mathrm{mod}\ \ \varpi^n$, $d\equiv 1\ \ \mathrm{mod}\ \ \varpi^n$. Another question is that $K(n)$ is the matrix congruence to identity matrix, I think that it won't be the kernel of $K_1(n)\rightarrow\mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{p}^n$
