Order of $(\mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{p}^n)^*$
Let $k$ be the non-archimedean local field, $\mathfrak{o}$ its ring of integer, $\mathfrak{p}$ the unique maximal ideal of $\mathfrak{o}$. Let the cardinality of residue field $\mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{p}$ is q, then is it correct that $|\mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{p}^n|=q^n$ for some integer $n$? Moreover, how to calculate $|(\mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{p}^n)^*|$? (I'm not sure if $\mathfrak{o}/\mathfrak{p}^n$ is still a field or not.)

Hint: what do you know about the units in a local commutative ring?

This question is inspired by the earlier question  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5001461/on-index-of-congruence-subgroups

You say you are not sure whether $\mathfrak o/\mathfrak p^n$ is a field.  Try the special case $k = \mathbf Q_p$ and $\mathfrak o = \mathbf Z_p$: is $\mathbf Z_p/(p^n)$ always a field?
The ring $\mathfrak o$ is a PID since every nonzero ideal is a power of the maximal ideal and the maximal ideal is principal (its generators are the uniformizers of $\mathfrak o$).  When $\mathfrak p = (\pi)$ and $S$ is a set of representatives for $\mathfrak o/\mathfrak p$ that includes $0$ as the representative of $\overline{0}$, show $\mathfrak o/\mathfrak p^n$ is represented by all $a_0 + a_1\pi + \cdots + a_{n-1}\pi^{n-1}$ where $a_i \in S$ and such a number represents an element of $(\mathfrak o/\mathfrak p^n)^\times$ if and only if $a_0 \not\equiv 0 \bmod \mathfrak p$.
